# How to edit chromium code to hide/remove address bar?

Tags: chromium

I have built chromium based on chromium.org. Now I need to modify the UI. I need to hide(remove) the address bar and also I need to disable the right click option. Could you please suggest (explain) which file I need to edit in-order to do this tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on my Ubuntu system right now, so I can't check it, but you should be able to run chromium in Kiosk mode.  It's a command-line switch "--kiosk".  This will disable the address bar for you.

For your reference, here's a full list of [Chromium command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

To get rid of context menus, use JavaScript on the page to capture the right-click (mouse button 2) and then simply ignore the input.

Comment: just tried `-kiosk` works just fine.

Comment: I am trying to edit the source code to fix it. How I can do it if I edit the source code?

Comment: Well, I'd search the source for the code that handles the -kiosk flag and make that the default state.  But I have to say, that seems like an odd question for a programmer to ask here.  You would likely get a better answer at The Chromuim Project (http://www.chromium.org/).  Just use the Discuss link and ask someone there.